# Adding a Column with Condition on Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

Been trying to figure this out for a while -

If I have a situation in which my pivot table gives me something along the lines of:

```
Row Labels              Revenues 

   Panera               25
        Pasta           15
        Salad           10

   Olive Garden         40
        Sandwich        20
        Pasta           20
```

and I wanted to insert a column next to revenues with 0's only for the rows with headers (panera, olive garden) and leave the rest of the rows for the orders blank - i.e.

```
Row Labels              Revenues    Order #

   Panera               25          0
        Pasta           15         
        Salad           10

   Olive Garden         40          0 
        Sandwich        20
        Pasta           20
```

is there a way to do this either in VBA, or just with a formula? Within my pivot table, the headers are labeled "restaurant name" while the subsets are labeled "orders", I was thinking about saying something along the lines of - if it's a restaurant name, insert 0, otherwise leave blank - but not sure how to do that or if there's an easier way?

Comment: If there is no overlap of names of restaurants and names of orders (i.e. you don't have a restaurant called "Pasta" for instance), you could use a formula such as `=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE),"")="","",0)` (assuming your pivot table was extracting the original data containing the restaurant name from column A of Sheet2)

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect! I just have one small question - instead of sheet2, my sheet name is something like "Food" - when I type in     =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,"Food",A:A,1,FALSE),"")="","",0) I get an error saying too many arguments, if I take out the comma between food and the range, I get a format error - is there a way to adjust for that?

Comment: You changed the `Sheet2!A:A` part of my suggested formula to `"Food",A:A`.  You should have changed it to `Food!A:A` (i.e. sheetname!range).  (Or if "Food" was just an example and you really meant something like "Food and restaurant", the spaces in the sheetname would require you to wrap it in `'` characters, so `'Food and restaurant'!A:A`.)

Comment: Got it - thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no overlap of names of restaurants and names of orders (i.e. you don't have a restaurant called "Pasta" for instance), you could use a formula such as

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,'Sheet2'!A:A,1,FALSE),"")="","",0)`

(assuming your pivot table was extracting the original data containing the restaurant name from column A of Sheet2)